# Take the highest role in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying the do ban command I want take the highest role of bot and to be banned I am using this commands :

```
let banlanan = message.mentions.users.first();
```

```
  let banlananroles = banlanan.roles.highest.position;
  let botroles = client.roles.highest.position;
  if (banlananroles > botroles) {
    message.channel.send("The role of the person you want me to ban is higher than me so I can't ban.");
    return
  }
```

*"banlanan" means to be banned person*

but I'm getting this error:

```
(node:7299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'highest' of undefined
at Object.exports.run (/app/commands/ban.js:58:38)
at Client.module.exports (/app/events/message.js:18:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8f956760-d64c-490a-a07c-4ad3ee571e52/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.4.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8f956760-d64c-490a-a07c-4ad3ee571e52/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.4.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8f956760-d64c-490a-a07c-4ad3ee571e52/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.4.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8f956760-d64c-490a-a07c-4ad3ee571e52/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.4.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8f956760-d64c-490a-a07c-4ad3ee571e52/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.4.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8f956760-d64c-490a-a07c-4ad3ee571e52/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/ws/7.4.0/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:196:13)
(node:7299) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7299) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

forgive me for my english ı used translator.

Answer (score 0):

[`Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) does not have a roles property. If you'd like to get the client's [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) instance, you should use [`message.guild.me`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me).

```js
let banlananroles = banlanan.roles.highest.position;
let botroles = message.guild.me.roles.highest.position;
if (banlananroles > botroles) {
 message.channel.send(
  "The role of the person you want me to ban is higher than me so I can't ban."
 );
 return;
}
```

Comment: I did it but my error still continues, the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error doing like this

```
let banlananrol = message.guild.member(banlanan).roles.highest.position;
let botrol = message.guild.member(client.user).roles.highest.position;
```

Thanks anyway